# Mysql Connections are string when checking from SHOW STATUS LIKE '%onn%';

Tags: mysql, connections

I have a Mysql db server which seems to be getting slow by time. When i am checking detail from SHOW STATUS LIKE '%onn%'; I get following details

```
Variable_name                                  Value   
---------------------------------------------  --------
Aborted_connects                               2       
Connection_errors_accept                       0       
Connection_errors_internal                     0       
Connection_errors_max_connections              0       
Connection_errors_peer_address                 0       
Connection_errors_select                       0       
Connection_errors_tcpwrap                      0       
Connections                                    2327    
Max_used_connections                           7       
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost  0       
Ssl_client_connects                            0       
Ssl_connect_renegotiates                       0       
Ssl_finished_connects                          0       
Threads_connected                              5
```

Is there anyway i can get the connections detail of the open connections?
Like source ip, username e.t.c.
Mysql version is 5.6

Comment: Connection details must be obtained from logs (and some data - from `show processlist`), not from status variables.

Comment: show processlist is not giving any deatils. which particular log should i check?

Comment: General log, of course... but 1) it must be enabled 2) it is too expensive for permanent logging. *Like source ip, username e.t.c.* Processlist gives this info (host->IP must be converted using proper namespace server logs or local ARP logs). What is 'etc.'?

Comment: It appears to me that connections must be a running total as I know I don't have 51000+ or even 1600+ if I subtract off the aborted ones. I can believe I've had 1600 since last reboot. Threads_connected is showing what is currently connected, which is what is listed via `show processlist`

Comment: topshot you mean's there seem to be no problem? Connections mean's number of connection since last db server have started?

Comment: I believe so. The docs say, "The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server." It would seem logical that is from last restart of the mysqld service.

Comment: I just bounced the service on my dev instance, and it reset connections back to 6 from 28.

Comment: `Connections` / `Uptime` is connections per second. -- That is the interesting thing to get from that value.  1/sec is about average.  25/sec is rather high.

Answer (score 0):

Their [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections) indicate that `connections` variable is,

> "The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL
>   server."

I just stopped and restarted the service on my dev server and `connections` dropped from 28 to 6.

[`Threads_connected`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_connected) is

> "The number of currently open connections."

and those are shown using `show processlist;`